# Electron w/ TensorflowJS--looking for napi-v4 but only napi-v5 present

Tags: electron, electron-builder, tensorflow.js

package.json has

```
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.4.0",
```

Here's the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\dist_electron\index.js
- C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js
-
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:717:15)
    at Function../lib/common/reset-search-paths.ts.Module._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:7609:16)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:622:27)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717:26)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:44:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:10)
```

If I go into `C:\Users\me\projects\myproject-desktop\project\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\` there is a `napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node` but no `napi-v4\tfjs_binding.node`.

Do I just need to downgrade tensorflowjs?  Anyone know what napi-v4 vs v5 is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to downgrade tensorflowjs (while waiting for the next release).

The solution would be to use node 10.16.3 and run the command:

```
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source
```

Comment: Only works with that version of node?  That could make life difficult.

Comment: There is a current issue tracked on github

Comment: I can't seem to find the issue?  Is it on electron's github or tfjs?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2341 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2370